# imaplib.IMAP4.error: command SEARCH illegal in state AUTH, only allowed in states SELECTED

Tags: python, django, imaplib

```py
def trash_view(request):
    global i, addr, passwrd, conn
    if request.method == 'POST':
        imap_url = 'imap.gmail.com'
        conn = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imap_url)
        conn.login(addr, passwrd)
        conn.select('"[Gmail]/Trash"')
        result1, data1 = conn.search(None, "ALL")
        mail_list = data1[0].split()
        text = "You have reached your trash folder. You have "\
        + str(len(mail_list)) + "mails in your trash folder.\
        To search a specific email say search. To go back to\
         the menu page say back. To logout say logout."
```

While I can work on `INBOX` , for `TRASH` section, it gives me this error `imaplib.IMAP4.error: command SEARCH illegal in state AUTH, only allowed in states SELECTED`. how can I solve this?

Comment: maybe this folder has different name. maybe first you should display all folders in Gmail

Comment: when use `print()` to see result from `select()` - `print( conn.select('"[Gmail]/Trash"') )` - then it shows `('NO', [b'[NONEXISTENT] Unknown Mailbox: [Gmail]/Trash (Failure)'])
`

Comment: when I use `print(conn.list())` then it shows me all my folders and I have `"[Gmail]/Kosz"` - it meas `trash` in Polish (my native language). Maybe you also have different name. BTW: it shows also `"Trash"` (without `"[Gmail]/"`)